# pass named list to ellipses in R function

Tags: r, ellipsis

I have written a function `funA`, which takes an unknown number of inputs and performs some calculations. The inputs are generated by another function `funB`, which returns a named list. Ideally, I would like to pass this named list straight to `funA`. However, the way I have written `funA` this causes an error...
Here is an example function which illustrates the problem:

```
sameLength <- function(...) {
  vecs <- list(...)
  numVecs <- length(vecs)
  if ( numVecs <= 1 ) {
    return(cat("Need two or more vectors."))
  }
  allSame <- TRUE
  len <- length(vecs[[1]])
  for ( i in 2:numVecs ) {
    if ( length(vecs[[i]]) != len ) {
      allSame <- FALSE
      break
    }
  }
  allSame 
}

output_funB <- list("a"=1:3,"b"=1:3, "c"=1:4)

sameLength(a = output_funB$a, b=output_funB$b, c=output_funB$c) # this works as intended, but is very cumbersome

sameLength(output_funB) # Ideally this is how the function should work
```

I am sure it is very easy to accomplish what I am trying to do, but I have not found a solution yet... simply changing `vecs <- list(...)` to `vecs <- ...` did not work unfortunately.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `do.call('sameLength', output_funB)`

Comment: Or if you want to use `rlang` you could do `eval(rlang::expr(sameLength(!!!output_funB)))`

Comment: In general, you should post the expected output for your sample input, **and** post the error you got.   As it stands, the experts have given solutions in the comments but aren't bothering with the "why," which would help future readers.

Comment: BTW,     `vecs <- (...)`  will get you what I think you want.

Comment: Well, `vecs<-(...)` wouldn't work with the non list version. Basically it would be the same as `sameLength <- function(x, ...) {vecs <- x; <rest of code>}` and the `...` would be unused. If you just want to pass in a list only, then don't bother with the ellipsis.